# how to control display switch_to_blog( $subsite->blog_id ); $tags = wp_tag_cloud

Tags: multisite

using get_sites I managed to display a list of WP Multisite Subsites with a variety of data pulled from the sites. However I cannot control where the tags are being displayed -- instead of showing up within the html elements, a tag cloud is displayed above the page content

```
/** get sites */

function make_list_shortcode()
{
$subsites = get_sites (
['number' => 500, 'orderby' => 'last_updated', 'order' => 'DESC', ]);
if (!empty($subsites))
    {
    $html = '<ul >';
    foreach($subsites as $subsite)
        {
        $subsite_id = $subsite->blog_id;
        $subsite_name = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->blogname;
        $subsite_link = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->siteurl;
        $subsite_domain = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->domain;
        $subsite_path = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->path;

// Switch to Blog
        switch_to_blog( $subsite->blog_id );
        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        $logo_image = get_theme_mod( 'fl-logo-image' );
        $custom_header = get_theme_mod( 'header_image' );
        $tags = wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' ) );

        restore_current_blog();
        // Added the image tag and src path
        $html.= '<li style="list-style: none!important; margin:10px 0; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;" class="site-' . $subsite_id . '" ><a href="' . $subsite_link . '" target="_blank"><img style="margin-right: 15px;" src="'. $logo_image .'" /><img style="margin-right: 15px;" src="'. $the_custom_logo .'" /><img style="margin-right: 15px;" src="'. $custom_header .'" />' . $subsite_name . '</a> ' . $site_description . ' '. $tags .'</li>';

        }

    $html.= '</ul>';
    return $html;
    }
}

add_shortcode('list_sites', 'make_list_shortcode');
```

The result is pulling tags from the subsite but also ignoring $tags in the html element completely.

I also have another question about how to insert an if function exists for the = get_theme_mod in looking for images - different themes use different methods and the way I have it generates 404 errors.

Truly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_tag_cloud()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_tag_cloud/) will `echo` the tags by default. Because this happens before your `return $html;` line, the cloud gets displayed above the shortcode content.

To prevent this, set the `echo` arg to `false`:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'echo'     => 'false',
);
$tags = wp_tag_cloud( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks Pat J, I ended up getting this to work      $tags = wp_tag_cloud( array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'echo' => 0) );        FYI for those interested I also added <base target="_blank"> to the head of the page to get all links to open new window.   BTW the last argument in a list like that should not have the period.  Still struggling with figuring out  if exists statements if anyone can help...  thanks

Comment: For the `if ( function_exists( ... ) )` question, you should [ask a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).